# Cant get PrintWriter to work

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I'm creating a save game file for a game but my `PrintWriter` just overwrites the file with nothing instead of the numbers I need.

Here's the code:

```
public void fileWriter() throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\stats.txt"));
    print.print(String.valueOf(this.swordNumber) + " ");
    print.print(String.valueOf(this.shieldNumber) + " ");
    print.print(String.valueOf(this.monstersDefeated) + " ");
    print.print(String.valueOf(this.damageDealt));
}
```

I've tried everything to get these variables printed including `String.valueOf` but its not working.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? If the file doesn't have any output, try `close` on the print writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should properly use Java's resource try-catch blocks. This will automatically close the stream even if any exception is thrown:

```
public void fileWriter() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\stats.txt");
    try (PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(file)) {
        print.print(Integer.toString(swordNumber) + " ");
        print.print(Integer.toString(shieldNumber) + " ");
        print.print(Integer.toString(monstersDefeated) + " ");
        print.print(Integer.toString(damageDealt));
    }
}
```

Also rather than `String.valueOf()` I suggest using `Integer.toString()` instead to make the type conversion more obvious.

Comment: Best answer. I like the note about using `Integer.toString()` too.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the stream before exiting,
and it didn't get flushed and closed properly.
Add this line when you're done writing:

```
print.close();
```

You should always close file handles after using them.

Even better, wrap the whole thing in a try-with-resources:

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\stats.txt"))) {
    // ...
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about closing it,
and therefore you can never "forget" it.